# display all users that current_user don't follows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship, railstutorial.org

I'm working on a Sample Application that's similar to Michael Hartl's [Railstutorial](http://railstutorial.org) and would like to display all users that the current_user is **not** following. How can I do that?

User.rb is:

```
has_many :following_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: :follower_id
has_many :leading_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: :leader_id
```

Relationship.rb is:

```
belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :leader, class_name: "User"
```

Comment: what rails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

@followingusers = whatever you have for users you are following

@notfollowingusers = User.where("id not in (?)", @followingusers.map(&:id))

Comment: Yes it works but how could I include the current user into the notfollowing users?

Comment: Try this.  @notfollowingusers = User.where("id not in (?) AND id not (?)", @followingusers.map(&:id), current_user.id)

Comment: Or you can just do @followingusers << current_user